# NEXT keyword not working for Outbound SMS in Mobileconnect Salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobileconnect

I have created 2 SMS in MobileConnect and I am using these SMS in journey builder.

1. Outbound SMS
2. Vote/Survey SMS with a keyword associated with it. E.g. "MYKEYWORD"

Now, when I use Outbound SMS in journey builder, user receives this SMS via journey and sends a reply to this Outbound SMS, second Vote/Survey SMS is not getting sent to the user. I have set "Next Keyword" as "MYKEYWORD".

Can someone please help me with this? Am I missing something here?